# How do I script the name of the excel online file to a cell?

Tags: excel, power-automate

I'm completely new at scripting.
Excel online - I have created a bunch of new excel files in Powerautomate, but I need the file specific filename inside each document. How do I do this?

I have found - console.log(workbook.getName()), this give me the correct "output", but I cant write it to a cell.
It is cell "B2", in spreadsheet "Data".

Hope you are able to help,
Thanks

Edit:
I have a pile of excel files that have been generated via MS Powerautomate.
Powerautomate is generating a specific name for each file. I need this file name inside each excel file, to do a specific filtering in a bunch of data.

The following picture are in Danish.
[screenshot of execl file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaaWk.png)
The name of this document is "Skabelon" and I would like to have this name automatically filled in spreadsheet "Data" "B2".

Is this possible?

//Mads

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: As requested.  I hope this helps.
Thanks